# Can Ubiquiti UniFi PoE switch be used as unmanaged switch before adopting?

Tags: networking, switch, ubiquiti, power-over-ethernet, unifi

I know some managed switches can just be used as an unmanaged switch out of the box, but I have a site with a UniFi US-16-150W PoE switch which nobody knows anything about how it is/was setup or passwords/controller information.

My question is: Does anyone know if I factory reset the switch can it just be used as an unmanaged PoE switch without adopting and without using the UniFi controller software etc?

I looked through the manual but it is not clear if the switch will operate or not out of the box (before adopting). And I would like to know the answer before I do a factory reset!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question as I was forced to do a reset of this UniFi.

Yes, it does appear that a UniFi switch (at least this one which is actually a US-8-150W not as I originally posted) can be used as an unmanaged switch out of the box. Both data and PoE are working.

I reset it, it's showing a steady white LED which according to the manual: "Factory defaults, waiting for integration".